Entropy for Adiabatic - Isochoric Cycle with single reservoir
Consider the following thermodynamic cycle for an ideal monoatomic ideal gas, conducted with the help of a single heat reservoir at Tres.

It can be shown that: $$\frac{T1 \times T3}{T4 \times T2} = 1$$ I am trying to calculate the total change in entropy, and I am getting two different results. When I try to calculate the entropy of the system where the total change in entropy is the change in the two isochoric processes:
$$ΔS = n\times Cv \times(\ln\frac{T3}{T2} + \ln\frac{T1}{T4}) = n\times Cv \times \ln 1 = 0,$$
and I cannot find any large mistake or any reason as to why any stage of this reaction should be irreversible and thus the entropy should increase.
My questions are:

Is the entropy change truly zero?
If the entropy does increase, why? Is a certain stage of this process irreversible?
If the entropy does not increase, how can we have a closed thermodynamic process with only a single heat reservoir? Does this not violate Thompson's Principle?


You have isochoric processes. I have no idea what you mean when you say that you only have a single heat reservoir $T_\text{res}$ when you have isochoric processes.

I’m sorry, I don’t quite get what you mean here. I was saying that unlike a Carnot process, where we have two heat reservoirs to play around with, here, we only have one at Tres.

I am trying to tell you that when you have 1) a well-defined enough thermodynamic process that you can even draw the line on the pV diagram, then it needs to be at least quasistatic, if not reversible, and 2) the isochoric process of that form necessarily has infinitely many heat reservoirs, not just one. Your question is thus lacking clarity if you do not understand that you have a fundamental mistake here.

You’re right, there’s something here I don’t quite understand. Could you please expand on what you mean by needing infinitely many heat sources for an isochoric process? Why would we not just be able to “couple” a container of fixed volume containing our ideal gas with a single Tres and call it a day?

Basic thermodynamics is built upon reversible processes. After all, you must first understand the simplest possible thing to consider, before you attempt to consider complications. Reversible requires quasistatic, or else you cannot even properly define the pressure, temperature, etc. Which means that if you want to heat something at constant volume, you must let it take infinite time to warm up to the infinitesimally hotter heat reservoir, and so on. It cannot be going quickly to the target temperature.

I think I’m starting to see it. Because we place our gas next to a heat reservoir, the temperature violently shifts in an uncontrollable manner, and so our process has become irreversible? And because our process is irreversible, we can no longer apply the isochoric entropy equation, since that is for reversible situations?

Yes, that is correct.

@naturallyInconsistent Unfortunately PV diagrams are commonly used when irreversible processes are involved. When they are it is specified that the pressure is external

Just because you say that this cycle can be executed using a single reservoir doesn’t mean that it can.

@BobD that is not drawn with solid lines like that. Maybe it would be dotted lines, or no lines whatsoever. And it is not often the case that the external pressure is sufficient to pin things down.

@naturallyInconsistent Agree. I have used dashed lines on ocassion.

I'm not sure how you came up with a single reservoir for the cycle, but it is impossible. It violates the Kelvin-Plank statement of the second law, which essentially says:
No heat engine can operate in a cycle while transferring heat with a single reservoir
That said, in answer to your summary questions:


Is the entropy change truly zero?


There is only one total entropy change of the system over a cycle, and that is zero. It doesn't matter if the cycle is reversible or irreversible. By definition, a cycle returns all system properties, including entropy, to their original state.


If the entropy does increase, why? Is a certain stage of this process irreversible?


While the entropy change for the system over a cycle is always zero, the total entropy change of the system plus the surroundings is greater than zero for an irreversible cycle. You would find that out if you calculated the entropy change of the surroundings for the two isochoric processes using a single temperature reservoirs.
In your example, the isochoric processes are irreversible because the isochoric heat addition (process 2-3) and heat extraction (process 4-1) processes involves single reservoirs (but not the same reservoir, as noted above). The heat transfers occurs over a finite temperature difference which makes them irreversible. To be reversible, you need to have an infinite series of thermal reservoirs ranging from the initial to final equilibrium temperature, not just single reservoirs. This is how you (correctly) calculated the entropy change of the system for the isochoric processes.


If the entropy does not increase, how can we have a closed thermodynamic process with only a single heat reservoir? Does this not
violate Thompson's Principle?


As already stated, you can't have a single reservoir since it violates the Kelvin-Planck statement of the second law.
Hope this helps.
